# using anonymous pipes for local interprocess communication on openframeworks 0.7.4 vs 2010

Tags: openframeworks, inter-process-communicat

I try to develop anonymous pipes for local interprocess communication, referring this article... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546102.aspx

I put this two lines in testApp.cpp

```
#using <System.dll>
#using <System.Core.dll>

using namespace System;
using namespace System::IO;
using namespace System::IO::Pipes;
using namespace System::Diagnostics;

void testApp::setup() {

}

void testApp:update() {

}

void testApp:draw() {

        Process^ pipeClient = gcnew Process();

        pipeClient->StartInfo->FileName = "pipeClient.exe";

        AnonymousPipeServerStream^ pipeServer =
            gcnew AnonymousPipeServerStream(PipeDirection::Out,
            HandleInheritability::Inheritable);
        // Show that anonymous pipes do not support Message mode.
        try
        {
            Console::WriteLine("[SERVER] Setting ReadMode to \"Message\".");
            pipeServer->ReadMode = PipeTransmissionMode::Message;
        }
        catch (NotSupportedException^ e)
        {
            Console::WriteLine("[SERVER] Exception:\n    {0}", e->Message);
        }

        Console::WriteLine("[SERVER] Current TransmissionMode: {0}.",
            pipeServer->TransmissionMode);

}
```

and they showed,

```
"Error:"#using" requires C++/CLI to be enabled
```

at the `#using <System.dll>`, so, on Project

`Properties->Configuration Properties->General->Common`

Language Runtime Support, I changed this from "No common Language `Runtime` Support" to "`Common Language Runtime Support (/clr)`".

Then I tried rebuild and got another error which is

```
Command line error D8016: '/ZI' and '/clr' command-line options are incompatible..
```

Now I completely lost..

Does anyone have a solution of how to build anonymous pipe on of 0.7.4??

Thanks in advance.

```
OpenFrameworks 0.7.4 / Visual Studio 2010 / compiler v100
```

Comment: Have you considered using Poco's Pipes?  They are available in openFrameworks and work well across platforms http://pocoproject.org/slides/150-Processes.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your comment! I try to use it and got this error....

```
Unhandled exception at at 0x7591C41F in emptyExample_debug.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: Poco::SystemException at memory location 0x0018F740.
```

the code that I debug is this...

```
void testApp::setup(){

    std::string cmd("bonanza.exe");
    std::vector<std::string> args;
    args.push_back("csa_shogi");
    Poco::Pipe outPipe;
    ProcessHandle ph = Process::launch(cmd, args, 0, &outPipe, 0);
    Poco::PipeInputStream istr(outPipe);

}
```